# How can I solve this indefinite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

Can someone please show me with steps on how to evaluate this indefinite integral?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Let $u = \sin x \implies du = \cos x\,dx$.

$$\int 3(\,\underbrace{\sin(x)}_{u}\,)^3 \,\underbrace{\cos x\,dx}_{du}= \int 3u^3 \,du$$

Comment: so the integral of 3u^3 would be 3/4u^4 ..?

Comment: Yes, $\frac 34 u^4 + C$. And then back substitute: that gives us $\frac 34 \sin^4 x + C$